# Render Z-stack of 2D images into 3D object in Blender

Tags: modeling, image

I try to follow Mike Pan's really short description how to rendering a stack of 2D images as a 3D object in blender found here: [Rendering stack of 2D images as a 3D object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8436/rendering-stack-of-2d-imageas-a-3d-object)

Mike writes: You can definitely render a 3D voxel dataset using the built-in tools of Blender. The basic workflow using the Blender Internal engine:

1. Create a Cube that's the same dimension as your voxel data
2. Create a volume material and texture for the cube.
3. Load in the density data as image sequence or 8bit raw data
4. Adjust all resolution parameters, and setup the texture to affect Density and Emissions.
5. Tweak color map and material properties until the data is shown nicely.

I am quit new to Blender. I only succeeded partly.

- I could make a cube that's the same dimension as my voxel data though opening the **Transform** panel in the **3D View Editor** by clicking the (**+**) symbol in the right top corner of the editor. There I could set the **Dimensions**.
- I could generate volume material and texture for the cube through opening the **Properties Editor**, where **Material** and the **Texture** for an object can be set.
- I got stuck by "*load in the density data as image sequence or 8-bit raw data*". 
  There are about 400 8-bit segmentation images I should load. 
  I could select them all and **Import** the **Images as Planes**. But I think this is not the way Mike aimed to load the z-stack of pictures. 
  How am I able to load the Images into the cube **?**

Every hint is appreciated!

Comment: Download the file example from his answer, you'll see that he added a texture of type voxel data and set voxel data path to the image ( the image is in 3d 490x410x1425 )

Comment: @Chebhou: Thank you. At least this helps me to understand where to set the path to the image file. Somehow I still not succeed. Should a tiff image which contains an 8bit converted z-stack work as 8bit raw image? If not, what what image format would it have to be? Do I have to render to see?

Comment: I will update the Mike Pan's answer

Comment: @Chebhou: Right now I am working with a beginners book form the blender store. I learned already a bit about the philosophy behind the interface and about modeling. Texture is following right afterwards, But I am not yet there and I doubt that they cover voxels. I assume this is a bit a special case. Whatsoever I know that blender can solve what I want to do. I am eager to learn. I am looking forward to the update of Mike Pan's answer. Thank you!

Comment: can you specify what you struggling with so i know what to address ?

Comment: Basically I have 2 z-stacks (folders) of png files. 
On have gray scale images, the other have black and white segmentation images. I assume this is about similar to the input that Mike had to generate his voxel model. 
[ImageJ / Fiji software](http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/Fiji) comes in handy to transform  the stack of images into a other formats, e.g one tiff file which contains the whole segmentation z stack.  (I am limited in space. I try to add a second comment after this comment.)

Comment: (I can not open a chat. I have not enough points. So I continue like this.) One basic question would be, which image format are supported to use as 8 bit raw or image sequence? There is not much information about  the specific format in the [man page](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/types/volume/voxel_data.html). Trying with tiff and png images did not work out. Or maybe It worked out, but I was not able to see a model like Mike's mouse skeleton.

Comment: I have tried with .rawb and Mike have used .img,  but i'll lookup what is compatible  , here is the example I'm using http://brainweb.bic.mni.mcgill.ca/cgi/brainweb1?alias=subject52_wht&download=1 try with this to make syre that you have the right setup

Comment: is the material and texture setup correct ? you should adjust the resolution

Comment: I do something wrong. 
I downloaded the rawb image from your link. I used Mike's cube. I set the Dimension (according to the length mentioned on the webpage) to X=3.62 Y=4.34 Z=3.62. The Texture Type is set to Voxel Data, File Format is 8 bit RAW, the Source Path I set to the rawb image file. I did not do any changes to the Material. 
So most probably I am not setting up Material and Texture correctly. Sorry.

Comment: @Chebhou it is quit [a file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bmg3z6l0m5o3wnu/segmentation.tif?dl=0) (278MB). This z-stack is now in tiff format. but it is easily possible to change the stack into an other format using [ImageJ/Fiji](http://imagej.net/Welcome) software. 
You said you were able to load the http://brainweb.bic.mni.mcgill.ca/cgi/brainweb1?alias=subject52_wht&download=1 .rawb z-stack as voxel into blender. Could save this as a .blender file and send me the link? I guess I could learn form that. Thank you for you effort!

Comment: here is [the .blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35935) and this is [the raw data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wdr0nlnvttqeoai/segmentation100x141x441.raw?dl=0) I had to resize it, it seems there is problem with the resolution of the original file, .TIFF format also works but you have to convert or resize the original file( you can use mine to  make sure the setup is correct

Comment: @Chebhou thank you for the .blender file and the adapted .raw data file! Finally I got output. 
This helps me much to understand how blender deals with voxel data. 
However, it opens as well new questions. I am not sure now, if I straight with blender can do what I like to do. I have to get more familiar with blender. I will post my final solution here as  answer. but this my take a while. 
Thank you for get me up and running! Elmar