# 3D modeling of blood vessels from 2D stack of labeled cross-sectional images

Tags: modeling

I'm having stack of 2D images with labeled cross-sections, want to fit 3D blood vessel model for the cross-sections having same label across the scans in the stack, similarly for all. Is it possible to do this in Blender?. First image is one out of 777 scans and second image is the view of the vessel in 3D by stacking 777 2D-scans.

Comment: It is quite possible, but I am guessing it will be extremely laborious and require extensive effort. For starters you would gave to trace your section images into something palpable like curves or meshes. You may also use curve objects or skin modifier to trace vessels. Not sure how to keep labels though, manually placing text objects seems unpractical.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide example images of what you currently have, and reference images what you want to achieve.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8436/rendering-stack-of-2d-images-as-a-3d-object

Comment: related if you just want to render: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62110/using-image-sequence-of-medical-scans-as-volume-data-in-cycles

Comment: But, I want a model of vessel in 3D, but not just the view getting by stacking all the 2D scans.

Comment: If you want a model you may need to look at external programs to turn the set of slices into some volume/ mesh data that blender can read.

Comment: Sazerac, Sorry I didn't get what is meant by external programs here.

Comment: A quick google suggests that variety of different programs that can generate either .obj or .stl files using slice data, which could then be imported into blender. I know of no way to do this entirely within blender at the moment. ImageJ/FIJI was an open source one that popped up a few times, so you could try investigating that.

Comment: Thank you Sazerac, FIJI helps me to get required .obj file, but Blender is not supporting to open this .obj file

Comment: Blender should be able to import the obj, any specific error you are getting? Also, if you feel like it and it ends up working, you could write up what you have done and and answer your own question.

Comment: FIJI helps me to get required .obj file from the stack of scans that fixes the problem.