# Time series animation of voxel data

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I would like to render a time series of image stacks using Blender voxel data similar to here: [Rendering stack of 2D images as a 3D object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8436/rendering-stack-of-2d-images-as-a-3d-object)

My original data are a TIF stack that contains XYZT data (time series of the slices interleaved). I can deinterleave it in any form, at the moment I have generated single files with z0000*Z*t0000*T* where *Z* and *T* are counting for slice number and frame.

How can this be done? I basically need to exchange the source files for every frame of the animation. It somehow seems not to be possible using drivers to manipulate the source files. I also thought about creating a script for the entire scene and replace the files by variables to generate every single frame of the animation with one run but this seems to be not the most efficient way.

I would be glad for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem in the mean time. Similar to here: http://pythology.blogspot.com/2014/08/you-can-do-cool-stuff-with-manual.html I used the Blender voxel data format (I also tried 8bit RAW, works too).