# No Voxel Data texture in Blender 2.82?

Tags: texturing

I would like to import a 3D object into Blender.

My object is formed by a sequence of images - a confocal stack, similar to an MRI scan (there are no surfaces, just a cloud of voxels). I know that what I want to do could be done in Blender 2.79 by giving a cube a texture called: Voxel Data, and then importing the sequence of images. They do it right in the first minute of this video (you may want to mute it):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PSPiUrrXsg

And also here:
[Rendering stack of 2D images as a 3D object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8436/rendering-stack-of-2d-images-as-a-3d-object)

Particularly this image is relevant:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTTfa.png]

However, everything looks very different in the current version of Blender, 2.82. I cannot see the option to edit the **Density**, **Reflection**, or **Emission** properties of a **"Material"**, and I cannot find the **Voxel Data** option for the **"Texture"**.

Comment: If you can, please, let me know if there is anything else that should also be updated in the tutorial/workflow by Chebhou and Mike Pan, which is here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8436/rendering-stack-of-2d-images-as-a-3d-object